# How does electron gun accelerates electrons?

Tags: electrostatics

I know that in electron guns we see in TV's and lots of other places, we have electron emitter (cold/hot W needle in the simplest case) and electrons are accelerated using lattice with high-voltage potential.

But the question is why doesn't this lattice slow down electrons once they passes through it?

PS. Please correct if lattice is not the correct word here :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say "electrodes" rather than "lattice." In a real CRT you have a very complicated set of electrodes, but let's pretend it's a parallel-plate capacitor with a hole in the positive-voltage plate. A parallel-plate capacitor has a strong field between the plates, but a very weak field on the outside. So once an electron flies out the hole, it feels very little field.

Comment: Zero exterior field is only strictly true in the limit of a infinite plate capacitor, but it is quite a good approximation.

Comment: @dmckee: Thanks for your comment. I've corrected "feels no field" to "fiels very little field."

Answer (score -4):

After traveling far away from the positive grid, electron has lost half of the energy that it gained when traveling between the electrodes.

Here's a numerical example that maybe explains why it must be so:

Electron that is shot from a far away position towards the negative electrode of an electron gun, loses 3 electron-volts of energy when traveling towards the negative grid, gains 6 electron-volts of energy when traveling between the electrodes, and loses 3 electron-volts of energy when traveling away from the positive grid.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I do not want to compete with such nonsense.

Comment: Where do you get this figure of 1/2? It doesn't sound right to me. Are you claiming that it's exact? Approximate?

Comment: "The positive grid" means he knows nothing, There are several positive grids in a CRT.

Comment: Your claim here amounts to *"the gun doesn't work because the electron loses the same amount of energy as it gains."*, which is nonsense. Perhaps you should look for a reference to back this up.

Comment: @dmckee: He says "Electron that is shot from a far away position...," which means that his claim isn't that the gun doesn't work. It's certainly true that when an electron is brought from infinity into some electrostatic device and them removed again to infinity, it ends up with the same energy it started with. It's also irrelevant. And I think the 1/2 is simply due to some conceptual confusion, such as a possible belief that when an electron is outside the plates it only feels the field from the nearer plate.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Electron that is shot from a far away position towards the negative plate of a parallel plate capacitor, loses 3 electron-volts of energy when traveling towards the negative plate, gains 6 electron-volts of energy when traveling between the plates, and loses 3 electron-volts of energy when traveling away from the positive plate. Energy loss must be equal to energy gain, and it must be symmetric. So exactly half of gained energy is lost when electron travels from positive plate to infinity.

Comment: @jartza: You answer is physically wrong even then because for roughly planar electrodes there is little field outside the electrodes (zero in the ideal limit).

Comment: @dmckee: many meters of weak field outside, a few millimeters of strong field inside

Comment: @jartza: No. In the limit of a the plate dimensions much greater than the separation *nothing* outside the thing. Moreover, a typical design for the initial gun does not start the emitter "far away", but near the cathode *inside* the field region. In particle physics we can keep throwing energy into electrons into the *tens of giga-electron volts* and send them swooping round accelerator rings miles in length. If your understanding were correct none of that would be possible.

Comment: Here is an example (this one does not use the parallel plate geometry). Notice that  the emitter is located in a region of high field? That's important for the initial pick-off

Comment: I know how you came by this answer...you're thinking a charge $e$ gets energy $V\text{ electron volts}$ when accelerated through a potential difference of $V\text{ volts}$, and you're trying to apply it to this case assuming that infinite distance represents a well defined base potential, but go back to a more basic definition. Use $W = \int q\vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}$ and think about the *field*.

Comment: @dmckee: this articles says that no, you can not use lined up charged capacitors as a particle accelerator: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29)