# Why does CERN use magnets instead of capacitor grids like an electron gun?

Tags: electrostatics, particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

The CERN tunnels use klystrons to accelerate the protons

https://home.cern/science/engineering/accelerating-radiofrequency-cavities

But electron guns use an electric field to accelerate electrons. Theoretically, shouldn’t we be able to use the same device to accelerate protons? The Output of this design would be a continuous stream of high energy protons instead of bunches.

Comment: Because you need to keep accelerating the particles as they go round and round - so electrostatics isn't the way to do it. Essentially the LHC is a linac wrapped around on itself.

Comment: Imagine the source of protons connected to a tunnel that opens up into a ring which has a bunch of the ‘parallel plate capacitors’ spaced evenly around. It is described here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/how-does-electron-gun-accelerates-electrons.    The protons should behave the same way electrons do - accelerating more and more each time they pass through another grid, no?

Comment: Nope, it just doesn't work that way - see, for example, https://cds.cern.ch/record/1982425/files/295-329%20Vretenar.pdf

Comment: Same for electron linacs, by the way. The ability to 'continuously' accelerate particles was the real advantage of linacs/cyclotrons/etc. over Cockroft-Walton or Van de Graaff electrostatic accelerators.

Comment: And, klystrons aren't magnets.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. It is mostly about rf accelerators. Yes i know i said magnets in the title when i should have been more specific and said oscillating magnetic field. But i still don’t get why a device like that in a crt cannot be used in series. From this reference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_particle_accelerator It seems that electric fields can be used which is basically the thing that accelerates electrons in a crt.

Comment: Re, "...why a device like that in a crt cannot be used in series." A CRT has a voltage, typically tens of thousands of volts, between its cathode and its anode. What happens when you put voltages in series?

Comment: are you saying there will be an arc between them? I read that unlike air, vacuum does not breakdown until theoretically it breaks only within the Quantum Field Theory because of the so called Schwinger effect Schwinger effect - Wikipedia i.e electron-positron creation from the energy density of the field under 10^12 MV/m = 1000000000000 MV/m. Realistically though no vacuum is perfect tho this link says the voltage would be very high https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335618/breakdown-voltage-in-vacuum